# style input box with jquery but have a fall back style

Tags: jquery, input, styling, dropdownbox

My problem is that when I style say an input or dropdown box with jquery, I read its best to also have a fall back in case the browser does not like my non-default styling.

I am not asking how to style via jquery, what I am trying to do is add a fall back (use default styling) when there's a browser problem.

I read this all the time but how to implement a fall back solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to use JavaScript to style a `<select>` or `<input>` field, I would suggest looking for a plugin that uses [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement), so that you don't compromise usability in older browsers.

Here's a good one: [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Comment: Chosen is amazing and my what I use most. So by using Chosen, I don't have to worry about a fall back because it utilizes progressive enhancement?

Comment: As Justin Bicknell said, the browser has default user-agent stylesheets that implement styles for these elements. The benefit of using a well-developed plugin like Chosen is that it degrades gracefully to those default styles for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: Thanks so much, it all makes since now...I am trying to load it via Wordperess and keep getting an error. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85824/chosen-jquery-library-not-loading-is-not-a-function-error

Answer (score 0):

The browser has default user-agent stylesheets used to style an input or drop down, or any other element for that matter.  So in a sense there already is a fallback.  If you are not satisfied with the default styles implemented in the user-agent stylesheet than you can write your own css to target these elements.